# Point out my mistake while converting TIFF to PNG/JPG

Tags: images, conversion, imagemagick, image-manipulation

This is a input tiff image, which I want to convert to JPG/PNG. [googledrive-link-to-download-sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rdOnCEMa9ew9fOV031h0Sk9zlovlFJdD/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

As general rule of thumb, I always use following command to convert between 2 image formats (mainly JPG to PNG ). `convert input.jpg out.png`

But:

```
convert input.tiff out.png
```

produces following image.
Could you point out why convert TIF to PNG is not working properly.
Is this something to do with colorspace/compressions?

[image]

Just in case: `$identify input.tiff` gives

```
input.tiff TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit YCbCr 619120B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Also, more info how images were made:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -y -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 fname.tiff;
```

Comment: Can you share the actual image? Maybe upload it somewhere and link it? That way we can test the solutions we try. We can't do that now since the image you've given us is a PNG.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added download link at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I found was, first converting `YCbCr` to `RGBA` using [tiff2rgba](http://www.libtiff.org/man/tiff2rgba.1.html). (included in `libtiff` package). Then convert that RGB tiff to any other formats.

```
$ tiff2rgba input.tiff out.tiff
$ convert out.tiff final.png
```

---

Additional info:

```
$ identify input.tiff
input.tiff TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit YCbCr 618733B 0.000u 0:00.000
$ identify out.tiff
out.tiff TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 858070B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

---

If you have more compact answers such as using only `imagemagick` without `tiff2rgba`, or even know why this would happen,
Please feel free to share. Thank you.

Comment: hm why go through rgba when there's no alpha channel and only grayscale

Comment: To be honest, I don't know any better. 
and I have same tiff images with colors to process.

Answer (score 8):

The `YCbCr` is the important point: That colorspace (it's a video colorspace, not RGB) is not converted, so either the PNG you produce has a colorspace annotation somewhere and your PNG viewer doesn't honor this annotation, or your `convert` is buggy and doesn't do the colorspace conversion even though it would need to.

`convert` has `-colorspace` option, so first thing I'd try is to explicitly set source and destination colorspaces, and see if it converts them that way.

Also, as the input pictures seem to be black and white, consider converting to a grayscale PNG (which would only need the Y or intensity channel).

Comment: The grayscale input image makes me think this might be a TIFF-encapsulated RAW image, in which case a proper demosaic filter will produce a color image.

Answer (score 4):

Since the colorspace information is part of the TIFF (that's partially what the T stands for: there's actual information about the structure of the image in the the file, it's *tagged*), this means your convert is doing something wrong (or, your input file is broken in a way that your other viewer can "incorrectly" deal with "successfully").

So, workaround: Don't use `convert`/imagemagick (which is also one of the largest source of server vulnerabilities in the history of the web). It's slow as hell, anyways, in my experience.

Try [`econvert`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/exactimage/econvert.1.en.html) from the [ExactImage](https://exactcode.com/opensource/exactimage/) project.

Other than that, Python PIL / Pillow might work beautifully; this is literally the first [example in their tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) (minimally modified); save this to a text file, mark it as executable and use it on your files.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys
from PIL import Image

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(infile)
    outfile = f"{filename}.jpg"
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            with Image.open(infile) as im:
                im.save(outfile)
        except OSError:
            print(f"cannot convert {infile}")
```

Comment: I actually used same method to convert it using Python. I'm just trying to use shell command rather than the Python.
I had to use some thing like `fnames = [i for i in os.listdir() if "tiff" in i]` then loop over everyfile.

Comment: that's **exactly** why I explained how this python code can bes used as an executable!

Comment: You still missed my point, I'm trying to explicitly *avoid* python (like losing a habit) in order to learn other stuff. But thanks for pointing to `econvert` tool. I faced some minor problem while installing it, but I'll test it in the future.

Comment: ah, sorry, yeah, I thought you weren't aware of the possibility to run python code as executables. I'd argue it's the right tool here – not a bad habit :)